# How do I reference a class function in Widget blueprint?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I have a very simple function I want to call from C++ class called CameraPawn in the Widget Blueprint. Here is the C++ .h and .cpp files

.h

```
public:
   UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
   void Test123();
```

.cpp

```
void ACameraPawn::Test123()
{
     GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-20, 1.f, FColor::Yellow, FString::Printf(TEXT("Button Pressed")));
}
```

Now, inside of the Widget Blueprint I created a button and a new variable of type of type CameraPawn object.

[Blueprint Widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uR2Qr.png)

I then assigned the button's onClick function to call the CameraPawn's Test123 function, but when I click the button, nothing happens. Is there a way to solve this?

[Calling Test 123](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QEq3.png)

Comment: Creating the variable doesn't spawn the pawn. Did you actually populate the variable with something?

Comment: Yes, I created everything that a class should have. It works when I put it in the BeginPlay of the CameraPawn class, but not when I press the button inside of the Widget.

Comment: Where do you populate the variable?

Comment: Well I don't know which variable you're referring to, but the function is public and inside the CameraPawn class.

Comment: The variable you created on the widget

Comment: It's created in the Widget Blueprint itself. How can I access the class if I don't either cast it or reference it.